# Downloading Games

Tags: pi-4, games

I am about to get a Raspberry Pi Model 4B. I heard you can get games like Minecraft, as it is in the Pi. What about games like Roblox and Fortnite? Can you get it? Please tell me.

Thank You!

Comment: why don't you do some research and come back if you have some questions

Comment: Since raspberry Pi runs on a modified version of linux, you could research how to install Roblox, Fortnite, etc on a linux operating system

Answer (score 3):

As you're probably aware, having read the [published documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/), and the [information on the `apt` package manager in particular](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/apt.md), there are numerous software packages available for easy installation on the Raspberry Pi.

The 'Advanced Package Tool' (`apt`) is your key to using this repository of software. With respect to your question regarding availability of a particular package, the `apt-cache` command will tell you if a software package is available in the repository. `apt-cache` is run from the command line (a terminal window), and is easy to use. Using your question as an example, here's how you would learn if the apps you're interested in are available under `apt`:

```
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ apt-cache --names-only search fortnite
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ apt-cache --names-only search roblox
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $
```

Since you know the names of the software packages I used the `--names-only` option in the `apt-cache` command. However, there are other ways to search if you don't know the name. You can learn the details by reading the `manual` for `apt-cache`; again, from the command line:

```
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ man apt-cache
```

Once you've finished reading, simply type the single letter `Q`, and you'll be returned to the command prompt.

But back to your question: As the results of the `apt-cache` search yielded no "hits", it seems likely that neither `fortnite`, nor `roblox` are available in the repository. You should NOT take this to mean that the packages cannot be installed and run on Raspberry Pi; there are many sources of software outside the `apt` repository. However, if you're just getting started, you may not want to "stray from the path" too far. Installing software from outside the repository is certainly possible, but there is some risk that you could "break" your system. Nothing at all wrong with breaking your system; just know that if you do, you may have to re-flash your SD card & start over.

If you've decided to proceed with installation of this software, start with a search term like "fortnite raspberry pi" in your favorite search engine, and see what turns up. Go from there... if you have a **specific** question at that point, you can ask for help here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Wine":`sudo apt install wine64`

wine lets you use windows apps on linux!

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. Yes you can play Minecraft, it tends to run very slow. The Raspberry PI is not a gaming computer. There are tools like wine, mame, Retropie, Pi-Kiss, PI-Apps that will help you install things. A lot of the games will not work on arm64, so you need to install the default arm7 Raspberry PI OS.
Take a few minutes to Read the Pi Docs before you jump in the water:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/
https://github.com/jmcerrejon/PiKISS
https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps
https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86
https://retropie.org.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi 4B is not strong to run high graphic games.Fortnite takes 29GB.
If you want to run , You must try to overclock it (but keep it cool instead of burning it , There is a possibility of catching fire :D ) and installing emulators like wine64.For more information about wine64 , go here :- [WineHQ emulator website](https://www.winehq.org/)

if you want to install wine , open terminal and enter `sudo apt install wine64`.
Hope you enjoy playing games !

Answer (score -1):

Im new to the Pi lifestyle but my kid plays roblox using some sort of Android emulation package to play it on her RPI4. AJ